# Gmail API OAUTH2 verify Desktop application

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, verify, google-cloud-console

At work we have developed an individual customer specific software application that is in use for a long time.  We have a new requirement in this same program to implement an option for sending emails directly from the program.

The user is able to add his own email account with the credentials and login through our program. For Microsoft and Gmail accounts OAUTH is implemented and something here is not very clear.

For Gmail-API we have made an OAUTH Client and Consent screen on Google Cloud Console which we need to publish and verify and here is where the problems start.  I am not very clear with the whole process of verifying the app.

In the steps for verifying is stated that we should verify a domain for the app, but this software is not hosted anywhere on internet and is not publicly available, it is available to a number of specific users (2000-3000).

Also Google requires a YouTube video of the software to be available publicly, which we are not able to upload because of customer requirements. Also here is required a Data Protection Policy page for the application which we as a developers don't have because we are only developing the software.

Other thing that is not clear to me, how is this type of software rated by Google, internal or public?

Have anyone experience with this or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifying an app for one of the Gmail scopes is a very complicated process. This process depends upon which scope of authorization you are requesting of the users.

In your case you are trying to send an email so you are using the [users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) method from the Gmail api.  This uses a restricted scope. Which means you will need to go though the full process.

First of  it doesn't matter if your application is hosted or not.  It also doesn't matter that you give this app to a limited number of users.  What matters is the scopes you are using.

1. You will need to ensure that your domain has been registered via google search console. So this app will need a domain
2. Once that is done you will be able to host your website, and the privacy policy on that domain.
3. You will need to create a YouTube video showing your application running, and how authorization is used.
4. You will also need to submit to a third party [security](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en#security-checkup) checkup of your application which is not free and will need to be done once a year.

All of this is needed because of your consent screen it doesn't matter if its hosted any where, It also doesn't matter if this is only available to  specific number of users.

If all of the users are part of a single google workspace account, that has created your client id and client secrete then you can set the app to internal and you wont need to be verified.  This only works for google workspace domain accounts.

Comment: Thank you. I am still not sure if I understood that correctly. We create individual software for our customers. These are CRM and ERP systems. For this we ONLY have to be able to send emails. We would like to use the module for sending emails with Oauth2 in all existing and new projects. It can't be that all of the projects have to go through the same verification process, to ONLY cover the case that one of the clients might be able to use a Gmail account to send. The effort is far too great. So we can not support Google. At Microsoft, oauth2 also works perfectly without this process.

Comment: Verification is triggered by the scope of authorization you need. Not the use case or limited use case of your application.   You need to be able to send emails from standard Gmail user accounts. You will need to be verified.    There is no way around it other then to Not use gmail to send emails.     Considering red tape and that the security verification process costs between $15k - $75k for restricts scopes like this.  I completely understand and your decision to not use google for this use case.

Comment: Welcome to stack please remember to accept the answer if it helped you.